# Filter rows based on a boolean column

Tags: macros, jinja2, templating, dbt

I am dynamically creating SQLs for each table via `macro.Details` of column and table name is stored in a seed file.

```
select table,
       columns,
       flag
from  {{ file }}
```

I am using `run_query` to execute the above query and assigning it to a list.

```
{%- set results = run_query(query) -%}

{%- if execute -%}
  {%- set table_names,columns,flag = [results.columns[0],results.columns[1],results.columns[2]] -%}
{%- endif -%}
```

Depending on the column `flag`, I have to group the CTEs and create two union CTEs separately:

```
flag_true as ( select * from tab1
            union
            select * from tab2) ,
flag_false as ( select * from tab3
            union
            select * from tab4)
```

I tried the below code but the problem is since my `table_names` loop have all `flag` values both true and false there is an extra union coming in the end.
I am unable to figure out a way to reduce the loop to only tables having `flag == true`.

```
flag_true as (
  {% for tab_name in table_names %}
    {%- if flag[loop.index-1]   %}
      select * from {{tab_name}} {% if not loop.last %}union{% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating your three lists `table_names`, `columns` and `flag`, based on your table columns, you are complicating the matter, as you are later treating them back as rows.

A better approach would be to filter your rows based on an attribute value, and this could be achieved with the [`selectattr` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) or its opposite, [`rejectattr` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.rejectattr).
I believe you can use those filters on [`agate.Table.rows`](https://agate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#properties), and since `run_query` returns a `Table` object, on `results.rows`, in your code.

So, something like:

```
{%- set results = run_query(query) -%}

{%- if execute -%}
  {%- set rows = results.rows -%}
{%- endif -%}
```

```
flag_true as (
  {% for row in rows | selectattr('flag') %}
    select * from {{ row.table }} {% if not loop.last %}union{% endif %}
  {% endif %}
% endfor %}
),
flag_false as (
  {% for row in rows | rejectattr('flag') %}
    select * from {{ row.table }} {% if not loop.last %}union{% endif %}
  {% endif %}
)
```